# Align five images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have five images I'd like to align horizontally, they're currently four aligned and the fifth below. Also they appear too centered, I would like to spread them a bit to the margins of the page.

Please let me know if you want me to paste my code, this is my first time posting here and I'm not sure how to include it, I didn't want the first post tolook too messy.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!tbp]

  \centering
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
\caption*{image1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2}
\caption*{image2}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image3}
\caption*{image3}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image4}
\caption*{image4}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.2\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image5}
\caption*{image5}
\end{minipage}
\hfill

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Yes, please paste the relevant part of your code in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), preferably just using `example-image-a` from standard tex distributions, rather than your own images.

Comment: Do all five fit in one line? Perhaps there just isn't room for the fifth one and thus it is placed on the next line?

Answer (score 2):

You should (a) reduce the widths of the five `minipage` environments from `0.2\textwidth` to either `0.19\textwidth` or `0.18\textwidth` and (b) omit the first and last `\hfill` statements. That way, the five graphs will be maximally spread out horizontally and there will be some whitespace in the four inter-graphic gaps.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % Omit "demo" option in real document

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!tbp]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image1}
\caption*{image1}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image2}
\caption*{image2}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image3}
\caption*{image3}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image4}
\caption*{image4}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.19\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image5}
\caption*{image5}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: In a follow-up comment, you asked:

> My next issue would be how can I spread them more to the margins of the page, they appear too centered, and how can I leave more space between them.

I must confess I'm not sure what you mean by "they appear too centered". The five images shown in the screenshot above are not centered -- they are fully spread out over the available textblock.

If you want more whitespace between the images, it's necessary to reduce their widths. This may be done by changing the widths of the enclosing `minipage` environments from the current value of `0.19\textwidth` to, say, `0.17\textwidth` or (even more drastically) `0.15\textwidth`. The following screenshot shows three rows of five images each, with each image taking up 19%, 17%, and 15% of the width of the textblock.

[image]

Comment: See Cvg's answer (that should have been a comment).

Comment: Please, don't edit my answer with further wish, what you like to obtain. Rather write a comment or new question. Anyway, see addendum to my answer. I will appear soon.

Comment: @Zarko - For the record: I did *not* edit your answer. I'm not sure why you posted this comment on my answer.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Many thanks for pointing out the OP's follow-up posting. I've provided an addendum in which I've addressed the issues raised in that posting.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants the images to extend into the margins a bit, as @Zarko's `adjustwidth` suggestion (though perhaps into both margins).

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - Thanks. Not knowing the page size and text block parameters (and hence also the widths of the margins) of the OP's document, I'm simply not in a position to give advice on how far into the margin the graphs should be allowed to protrude.

Comment: Mico, I'm very sorry, this comment was indented to OP, not to you. My big mistake, I miss a place where to insert my comment (below my answer, not above). My answer was edited by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `tabularx` instead of `minipage`s make code more concise and also take care about their width and spreading along text width. To see this I in MWE below add `showframe` package which only serve to show page layout (and in real use had to be deleted):

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % Omit "demo" option in real document

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} *{5}{X} @{}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1}
\caption*{image1}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2}
\caption*{image2}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image3}
\caption*{image3}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image4}
\caption*{image4}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image5}
\caption*{image5}
\end{tabularx}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to increase or reduce distance bteween image, you only need to change `\tabcolsep`:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{<desired width>}
```

Its default size is 6pt.

**Addendum:**
I a case, that you like to spread images in width wider of text width, you can use package `changepage` and his macro `adjust width`. For example, that you like to extend images to outer bother:

```
\begin{adjustwidth*}{0 pt}{<right margin>}
 ... images ...
\end{adjustwidth}
```

In example below the space for table with images is extended into space for `marginpar`s:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% Omit "demo" option in real document
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage} % <-- added for change of total images width
\usepackage{calc}               % <-- added for calculation of total images width
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

\begin{document}    
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{adjustwidth*}{0cm}{-\marginparwidth-\marginparsep}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} *{5}{X} @{}}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image1}
\caption*{image1}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image2}
\caption*{image2}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image3}
\caption*{image3}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image4}
\caption*{image4}
    &
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{image5}
\caption*{image5}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{adjustwidth*}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]